# Recover files from gedit

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery, gedit

I suspended my laptop while writing some files in gedit. When I opened my laptop, it suddenly went off and lost the files I had open in the text editor. How can I recover those files?

[image]

I have tried using the terminal, and I have tried Nautilus, but I can't even access Nautilus on my Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 10):

By default, the text editor (Gedit) *does not* autosave documents [*unless* you manually saved them at least once beforehand](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2291165). So if you didn't save your file, it's lost, unfortunately.

If you *did* save your file, the newer autosaved copy is in the same place as where you saved the file, but with "`~`" appended. This is a hidden file, so enable "Show hidden files" in the file manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>), or use `ls -a` in the terminal to see it.

Comment: But i saw , autosave of the copy of each file you open on text editor

Comment: @Jay I don't understand what you mean by this, could you clarify ?

Comment: Kindly please see my question, i just added a picture of what i am trying to tell you , it was just like that , it displayes " save backup copy of files or something" @jonazCs

Comment: when i check the hidden files on my system , it didnt find the copy of my lost file

Comment: What Jonas said is that the files are not auto-saved before you don't save them manually for the first time. I fear your work is lost...

Comment: What is hidden depends upon the application. Unless you change the option it is hidden in Nautilus as you said. It is not hidden to `ls`. It is entries starting with a dot (.) that are hidden to `ls`. The man entry for `ls` says of the `-a` option "do not ignore entries starting with `.`"

Comment: This is a compelling reason for ditching once and for all.

Answer (score 4):

There is an [issue opened for the feature of saving drafts](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=682977), but it has not yet been resolved.

You could try to use [this plugin](https://github.com/dsoprea/GeditSafetySave).

Comment: This is the other good reason for ditching Gedit, as much as I love it.